# Python multithreading with local dictionary to speed up process

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a process that is very slow, and I want to speed it up using multithreading. The goal of my process is to read through a very large dataset and do an expensive calculation on each line, then store the result in a dictionary. I want to use multithreading but I am not sure how. Here is my attempt.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def findTweets(side):
     cosine_dict = {}
     for t in tweets:
            topic = [side, t]
            tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
            topic_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(topic)
            cosine = cosine_similarity(topic_matrix[0:1], topic_matrix[1:2])
            cosine = float(cosine)
            key = side + "&&" + t
            cosine_dict[key] = cosine
     return cosine_dict

left = [] #just some strings

for l in left:
       pool = ThreadPool(processes = 10)
       result = pool.apply_async(findTweets, (l,))
       cosine_dict_left = result.get()
```

This does not seem to be speeding up performance. How can I apply multithreading here to speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

`result.get()` is a blocking call. So you're only running one task at a time. A dirty fix would be:

```
left = [] #just some strings
results=[]
pool = ThreadPool(processes = 10)

for l in left:
       results.append(pool.apply_async(findTweets, (l,)))

for result in results:
       cosine_dict_left = result.get()
       #Do something with cosine_dict_left
```